# building objects from xml file at runtime and initializing, in one pass?

Tags: c++, xml, algorithm, optimization, parsing

I have to parse the XML file and build objects representation based on that, now once I get all these data I create entries in various database for these data objects. I have to do second pass over that for value as in the first pass all I could do is build the assets in various databases. and in second pass I get the values for all the data and put it in the database.

I have a feeling that this can be done in a single pass but I just want to see what are your opinions. As I am just a student who started with professional work, experienced ppl please help.

Can someone who have ideas or done similar work, please provide some light on the topic so that I can think over the possibility of the work and get the prototype going based on your suggestion.

Thanks a lot for your precious time, I honestly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in learning several techniques of building XML parsers like [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). As it is said in SAX description the only thing which requires second pass could be the XML validation but not the creating the tree.

Comment: it's complicated and I have to dig more stuff out

Answer (score 0):

Beside DOM and SAX parsing, you can use XQuery for querying data from XML files.It is fast, robust and efficient.

[here is a link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/)

You can use Qt Xml module for DOM ,SAX and XQuery, btw it is open source.

Another option is xml - C++ data binding, [Here](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsde/documentation/cxx/parser/guide/) is the link.You can create C++ codes from definition directly.It is an elegant solution.

EDIT:

the latter one is at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache Licensed http://xmlbeansxx.touk.pl/. It works under Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at the somewhat simpler 'pull' api called [stax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) instead of using sax (event based).